# Derived \coordinate in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Why the code not produces the line?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (A)+(1,0);
    
    \draw (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because what you've done is to add the `B` coordinate at the same place as `A`.

This is because `(A)+(1,0)` is not a single coordinate specification, what it does is to first move "pen"/active point of the path to `A` and then move that active point 1 unit right. I guess `\coordinate (B) at ..` grabs the next coordinate it sees, and that is `A`.

There are various options for defining new coordinates relative to other ones. You can add a `shift`:

```
\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(1,0)}]A);
```

You can add it as part of a path:

```
\path (A) +(1,0) coordinate(B);
```

This works because we start the path at `A`, then move the active point 1 unit right and add the coordinate at this point.

With `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` you can use the `($...$)` syntax for coordinate calculations:

```
\coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(1,0)$);
```

Or with `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` you can use the `right=of` syntax for node positioning:

```
\coordinate [right=1 of A] (B);
```