# How to navigate away from a given point in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I know this is a very basic question but I somehow have not found an answer to this searching through the documentation (although I have to say it is probably my bad).

But how am I able to navigate from a given point in a tikz graphic? I am using tikz and tkz-euclide. And if I grab any point in space, how do I define another point to just be +1 in every direction away from that one? Like if I have my point A at (1/1) and I want A' to always be 1 away in x direction and two away in y direction, how do I do that?

If this helps:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
```

Comment: For TikZ, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632054/derived-coordinate-in-tikz/632065#632065 I'd think `tkz-euclide` has something similar, but I haven't looked at the manual to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Derived \coordinate in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632054/derived-coordinate-in-tikz/632065#632065) for various ways of defining relative coordinates with plain TikZ.

`tkz-euclide` has `\tkzDefShiftPoint` for this sort of thing, e.g. `\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](1,2){A}` to define `B` 1 unit lengths right and two units up relative to `A`.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);

\tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](1,2){B}
%\path (A) ++(1,2) coordinate (B);
%\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(1,2)}]A);
%\coordinate [above right=2 and 1 of A] (B); % requires positioning library
%\coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(1,2)$); % requires calc library

\draw [->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you so much for this reply!

Comment: @TomGöbel By the way, I think all those methods except the `above right` one lets you use polar coordinates with `(<Angle>:<distance>)` instead of xy-coords. If you need that.